# How do Gradient Boosted Trees in Regression work?

Tags: tree, machine-learning, binary-tree, gradient

I am having an issue understanding how Gradient Boosted Trees work. I tried to follow this link here:

http://www.statsoft.com/Textbook/Boosting-Trees-Regression-Classification

but this was not very helpful. So I am under the impression that

1. You divide the data into partitions
2. You try to find a line of best fit to predict the data points on each partition
3. You calculate some sort of error (Residual Sum of Squares) for each partition
4. You create another tree and based on the errors of the previous tree, you try to find another partition that will further reduce the overall RSS of the entire equation and repeat until you have created a certain amount of trees.

I am confused on a few aspects:

What is the point of these partitions? Why can't I find the RSS of a tree without doing a partition? Also, I read that the final predicted value is formed by adding the weighted contribution of each tree. What is each tree outputting? Is each tree outputting its own prediction of the final predicted value? What is each tree made of?

If you could let me know that would be much appreciated. Thanks!